# Icons not rendering along with template result | 404 error

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to render icons that match a search, but I am getting a 404 error for `http://localhost:3000/static` when I search a value

Currently, my relevant folder structure is as follows:
`Base directory > Public > Icons` and `Base directory > index.js`  .

Inside of my index.js express server file, I am using `app.use("/static", express.static("public/icons"));` to allow the server to access the icons, however on my front end I am receiving a 404 error for Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) as previously mentioned

In my ejs template, I am attempting to render these icons by using

```
<img alt="" src="/static/ <%= country.icons %>" /> <%= country.name %>
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix this, and render my icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things that could be happening here:

1. Verify you are receiving a valid `country.icons` in the template.
2. You have a space between `/static/` and `<%= country.icons %>`. That is surely causing problem.
3. You also need to put the file extension of the image or icon that you have in `public/icons` folder. For eg, if you have png images, you'll need to change it to:

```html
<img alt="" src="/static/<%= country.icons %>.png" />
```

It would be even more helpful if you give more context by adding an image of what request is being sent from the frontend i.e via the Network tab in the developers tool.